# Check duplicate indexes that is combination of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a unique index (UQ_index1) created using

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_index1 on product_table
(
  column1,
  column2
)
INCLUDE
(
  column3
)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE)
ON scheme_Product(column1)
```

1. Somehow my table is messed and I've few duplicate rows in table. How
   can I create a **query that will help me get the duplicate items with
   combination of three columns (column1, column2, column3)** in the product_table
2. What is the suggested **ways to get ride of duplicate key situation**?

Comment: Beware! INDEX(col2, Col1) INCLUDE(Col3) will not have the same behaviour as INDEX(col1, Col2) INCLUDE(Col3) because a BTree index is a sort of vector...

Comment: @SQLPro The message is "The duplicate key value is (val5, val6, val7)". will this values be same order as col1, col2, col3? I wanted to simply use select statement with WHERE col1= val5 AND col2 = val6, AND col3 = val7? but I'm not getting any such result for this statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple group by query should be sufficient to return the duplicates

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM product_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I am not sure what you mean by duplicates, as your unique index does not allow duplicates.

Comment: somehow the table is messed up and while copying it to the the other backup table with same properties we get cannot insert duplicate key error

Comment: @Oliver The message is "The duplicate key value is (val5, val6, val7)". will this values be same order as col1, col2, col3? I wanted to simply use select statement with WHERE col1= val5 AND col2 = val6, AND col3 = val7? but I'm not getting any such result for this statement

Comment: I don't know where the message comes from. You should be able tell it from the content and these values should appear with my select statement, if really all 3 columns must be unique. Otherwise, if only the 2 first must be unique, drop column 3 (twice). What I can say is that if the values are from text columns, they need to be surrounded by '. Like `WHERE col1= 'val5' AND col2 = 'val6', AND col3 = 'val7'`

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the duplicates using:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             count(*) over (partition by column1, column2) as cnt
      from product_table p
     ) p
where cnt > 1
order by cnt desc, column1, column2;
```

It is not clear what you want to do to get rid of the duplicates.  If you just want to wantonly delete duplicates, you can use `delete`:

```
with todelete as (
      select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by column3) as seqnum
      from product_table p
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

However, you have other options:

- Updating one of the columns so they are not duplicated.
- Adding another column to the unique index to get around the duplicates.

Comment: simply adding column3 above will work I guess to get combination of column1, column2, column3 will work I guess?
By updating one of the columns I assume you meant ensuring combination of all three columns are unique

Comment: @RahulSingh . . . Yes, that is what I mean by "updating".

Comment: The message is "The duplicate key value is (val5, val6, val7)". will this values be same order as col1, col2, col3? I wanted to simply use select statement with WHERE col1= val5 AND col2 = val6, AND col3 = val7? but I'm not getting any such result for this statement